# AWS lambda call with urllib3.PoolManager().request() -> {'message': 'Forbidden'}

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, urllib3

I have a lambda on AWS and I use it with `urllib3`.
It worked for a month.

Today I tried it and now I can't access it. it returns me this: `{'message': 'Forbidden'}`

```
import urllib3, json

http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs = 'CERT_NONE')#
http.verify = True

def get_request(url):
    print("sending GET request at",url)
    try:
        r = http.request('GET', url)
        response = json.loads(r.data.decode("utf-8"))
        print("api_connector request:",response)
        return response["statusCode"], response["body"]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("http request failed")
        return -1, str(e)

err, err_msg = api_connector.get_request(
            "https://xxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxxxxx?filename=" + filename)
```

I saw some posts about this error but:

1 - talking about crawling others' websites when I'm talking about my lambda! so nobody should stop me?

2 - it was working before and one day, it stopped... so what should I try? I'm kinda lost :/

Comment: You talk about "lambda" but you're calling (and getting the forbidden response from) API Gateway. Try calling that service outside of your code, e.g. from postman. And note that you get that same error when the url is wrong, maybe something changed on that API's side.

Comment: Looks as though the API you're accessing is incorrect now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out it was because because a friend added a AWS certificate on the API Gateway.